# Unknown table in multidelete without joins

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a value from a field in workbench.

Getting an error

> Unknown table nhs in multi delete

I am trying to "NULL" a single filed in a single table.

```
DELETE nhs FROM persons WHERE oid = 123
```

I was expecting this to delete the record. Whats wrong? I am only trying to delete a value from a single field in one table.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. You need to start with `DELETE FROM persons ...` I mean Remove `nhs` after `DELETE`.

Comment: _I am trying to "NULL" a single filed in a single table._ Are you looking for `UPDATE persons SET nhs = NULL WHERE oid = 123` ?

Comment: Thanks - Could you elaborate please?  How do i tell it what to delete?  I want to delete the NHS number

Comment: I don't think you quite understand DELETE deletes a row from a table(or tables) An UPDATE changes column values in a table (or tables) please refer to manual

Comment: You're right....i dont.  I thought that this was a helpful site that helps people understand.  Must be my mistake hance the down vote.  It just appears to be scattered with helpful people but the majority are just here to point out the flaws in other peoples abilities.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to "NULL" a single filed in a single table

I hope you are looking for

```
UPDATE persons SET nhs = NULL WHERE oid = 123
```

`DELETE FROM persons WHERE oid = 123`, will remove the entire row, it can't delete a single column. To change a single column's value you need to use `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Logically to me, delete ws the right one to use but updalte also fits.